# Opencart generates wrong hash for password

Tags: opencart

I am having hard times logging in as Administrator in Opencart.

somehow admin/admin I created earlier works fine, but when I create a new user in the admin panel I cannot log in. It says the password or email is incorrect.

I checked the database. Everything is being added there.

Then I tried to chenge the hash string of password to another directly in the database. I generated it on another site.
And after that I am able to log in.

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: What version of OC are You using? Password hashing (+salting) has changed since OC 1.5.4 (salting was added, versions prior to 1.5.4 don't salt the passwords and are using only `md5()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you change anything in the database schema or the controller/model files?

Hashing algorithem normally don't get changed without a reason.

Did you install any related new plugins?

If you haven't, I suggest checking:

1. Create a new user, try to login and goto Admin->System->Error Logs. Look for clues.
2. Make sure you have the correct permissions to the files if this is done on a hosted solution.
3. Make sure your Encription key is correct, goto Admin->System->Settings->Server and see if it's ok. It should be exactly 32 characters long.
4. If you're fluent with the MVC and php, goto matching controller and model files and do var_dump() to see what information they actually get.

If all these don't help, post your findings here again, I'll try to help further.